# Troubleshooting MSYS64 Installation Issues

Tags: development-environment, mingw-w64, msys2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P3Ky.png)
I’m encountering issues while trying to install MSYS64 on my computer. Can anyone provide a solution for this?

I tried to reinstall many times, and it still has those issues. Would anyone be able to assist me, please?

Comment: looks like an issue with your internet connection or the msys mirror you're using

Comment: Are you using a proxy server or behind a firewall that is filtering web traffic?